# htaccess redirect index.html to index.php for domain root only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a htaccess rule which redirects the index.html to index.php

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1index.php [R=301,L]
```

This works fine - when I call http://mydomainname.com/index.html , it redirects me to http://mydomainname.com/index.php

but I got one problem, when there is a file in subfolder named index.html then my htaccess rule takes that to index.php.

Example - http://mydomainname.com/subfolder/index.html to http://mydomainname.com/subfolder/index.php and this should not happen for subfolders.

Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That rule is probably a bit over-complicated for what you're doing.

You only need:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php [R,L]
```

Comment: `[R]`:Redirect, `[L]`:Last - doesn't process any more rules though I have a feeling `[R]` on its own implies `[L]` anyway

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It work's in my case.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
```

Visit: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-redirect-indexhtml-to-indexphp/