# htaccess redirect issue from same file name to same file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have created the PHP website with some .php files and some .html, it means some files has dynamic content and some files will static.

For dynamic pages I have already done the redirection. The redirection like category page, products list and product details page like the below:

> http://localhost/project_name/categories.html
>
> http://localhost/project_name/category-name/product-name.html

Now I want to redirect static pages like the below:

> http://localhost/project_name/factory.html

I have added the condition for that page in my .htaccess like the below:

```
RewriteRule ^factory.html$ factory.html [R,L]
```

I have gone through the below answers:

[htaccess redirect index.html to index.php for domain root only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188604/htaccess-redirect-index-html-to-index-php-for-domain-root-only?answertab=active#tab-top)

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-redirect-indexhtml-to-indexphp/

Please check my below complete .htccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews

Options +FollowSymLinks

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /granite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^factory.html$ factory.html [R,L]

RewriteRule ^monuments-tombstones.html(.*) monuments-products.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^monuments-tombstones+/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ mproduct-detail.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^cobble-setts.html(.*) cobble-products.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cobble-setts+/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ cproduct-detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z-]+.html?$ products-category.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html?$ product-detail.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

Please help me out this issue.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Exact problem is page isn't redirect properly when I add this rule `RewriteRule ^[contact]+.html contact.html [R,L]`

Comment: @starkeen I want to redirect `contact.html` page on `contact.html`, but when I visit the `http://localhost/project_name/contact.html` it's showing me blank page.

Comment: So you want to redirect `/file.html` to `/file.html` (identical destination ). ? Well,this isn't possible. If both new and old urls are same then you will get an infinite loop error from the Rewrite Engine.